# Best way to sort vector to middle big(front & end small)

Tags: c++, sorting

```
std::vector<int> arr = {2,1,3,4,5};

middle_big_sort(arr);
```

after sort

```
arr == {2,4,5,3,1}
```

My solution:

```
std::vector<int> middle_big_sort(const std::vector<int>& arr) {
    std::vector<int> temp1 = arr;
    std::vector<int> temp2 = arr;
    std::vector<int> ret;
    std::sort(temp2.begin(), temp2.end());
    std::sort(temp1.begin(), temp1.end(), std::less<int>());
    temp1.insert(temp1.end(), temp2.begin(), temp2.end());
    ret.reserve(arr.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < temp1.size(); i+=2) {
        ret.push_back(temp1[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Is there faster way?

Comment: what did you try? what is the actual problem?

Comment: I guess you know you can sort normally the array, and then perform a permutation. What is your issue? Modify this process? Perform the permutation in a simple way ( if it is possible)?

Comment: What's your accurate definition for ` middle big`

Comment: arr middlest is the biggest,and middle left second biggest,middle right third biggest,arr front and end smallest like {2,4,5,3,1} .@prehistoricpenguin

Comment: You seem to have a working algorithm, so the question is about speed?

Comment: Yes,speed faster,better.And code should be elegant.@OznOg

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try something like this that prevents some copies and sort operations.

```
auto middle_big_sort(std::vector<int> arr) -> decltype(arr) {
    decltype(arr) ret(arr.size());
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    arr.push_back(arr.back()); // prevents messing with boundaries in loop
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.size() / 2 + 1; i++) {
        ret[ret.size() - i - 1] = arr[i * 2];
        ret[i]                  = arr[i * 2 + 1];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

but there must be more optimal solutions...